# send multiple checkbox vales to controller using ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

i have download the Microsoft Music-Store application so i am making some changes in that so what i am changing is that Album model consisting of (id, title, genreId, artistid......) so i want to display list of Album based on genreid using Checkboxes whatever the checkboxes i clicked the list should be displayed so i written the code like this.

here i have small problem what that means when i go to GenericList view where all genre name are displaying(showing in every genre name with checkbox this checkboxes are unchecked) but list of album is not showing (where all checkboxes are unchecked list should be displayed) when every i checked some checkboxes it displaying exactly but unchecked all checkboxes list of album are not showing.so please help me what changes i have to make

**Controller:**

```
   `public ActionResult GenericList()
    {
        ViewBag.Generic = db.Genres.ToList();
        return View();
    }`

public ActionResult _GenreList(string cbk)
    {
        var listIds = new List<Int32>(Array.ConvertAll(cbk.Split(','), Convert.ToInt32));
        var list = from a in db.Albums
                   select a;
        if (cbk != null) 
        {
            list = from l in db.Albums
                       where listIds.Contains(l.GenreId)
                       select l;
        }
        else
        {
            list= from a in db.Albums
                  select a;
        }
        return PartialView(list);
    }
```

**ActionResult**

```
 <ul id="checkboxFilter">
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Generic)
    {
    <li>
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cbk" id="@item.GenreId.ToString()" /> @item.Name
        </div>
    </li>

    }
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cbk').change(function () {
        var ID = "";
        $('.cbk').each(function (index, val) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                ID += $(val).attr("Id") + ",";
                alert('id Name: ' + ID);
            }
        });
        var data = {};
        data.cbk = ID.slice(0, ID.length - 1);
        if (ID != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/_GenreList',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#Generic_list").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went Worng.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `public ActionResult _GenreList(string[] cbk)
        {
            var list = from a in db.Albums
                       select a;
            if(cbk !=null)
            {
                list=list.Where(x => cbk.Contains(x.Genre.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                list = from a in db.Albums
                       select a;
            }
            return PartialView(list);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the same name for all the checkboxes in the group e.g. `"name"="genres"`

and value attribute to the value you want to pass to the controller e.g. `"value="@item.GenreId.ToString()"`.

Then in the controller, you'll receive a genre array e.g.

`public ActionResult _GenreList(string[] genres)`

Comment: see: http://www.gunaatita.com/Blog/Send-multiple-checkbox-values-from-view-to-controller-in-MVC/1047